# Is it possible to generate an access token for a Google Cloud Platform API in a Cloud Function?

Tags: android, google-cloud-functions, google-speech-api

I currently have an Android app which utilizes the Google Speech-to-Text library. During development, I have a Service Account JSON file in /res/raw/, which I use as credentials for the API.

I've added Firebase Auth UI to the app, and I now want to provide credentials to the Speech-to-Text API through Firebase. Is that possible using Cloud Functions (generate a token based on the Firebase Service Account), if so, how do I obtain it?

I could not find any documentation related to generating access tokens within a Cloud Function.

Comment: You want that you android app call your Cloud Function for getting the authentication token, and then  your Android can will be able to reuse it for query the speech to text API, don't you?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes, essentially. I would ideally like to do this during log in.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere sorry, i should have been more clear. My question has been updated.

Comment: What's your language? I can send you a sample if you want.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere that would be great if you could! My app is in Java and I am using Javascript in Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node is the language with which I'm the less confortable. Here a minimal example for generating an access token based on the [Cloud Function identity](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');
const auth = new GoogleAuth()
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    res.send(await auth.getAccessToken());
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {});
```

*You have to add `google-auth-library` in your dependencies*

There is no authentication (you have to be sure that the requester is authorized, I mean your user logged in your Android App, I assume with firebase auth) and the access token is returned in plain text (no json format).

I think you can adapt this.